# Showing OutputDebugString messages with Window application?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, cmd, window, message

I'm working on Windows application and would like to use `OutputDebugString` function to output debug messages to the console while the window is running.

the problem is I don't know how to achieve this.
If I run window app from Visual studio no console is shown because it's the **windows/subsystem:windows** in linker setting

and if I run the window program from the console the command line terminates emidiatelly after showing the window.

How would I achieve to show CMD and window in the same time to see debug messages passed to `OutputDebugString` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) from sysinternals to capture and show those debug messages:

> Under Windows 2000, XP, Server 2003 and Vista DebugView will capture:
>
> Win32 **OutputDebugString** 
> Kernel-mode DbgPrint 
>  All kernel-mode
>   variants of DbgPrint implemented in Windows XP and Server 2003
>   DebugView also extracts kernel-mode debug output generated before a
>   crash from Window's 2000/XP crash dump files if DebugView was
>   capturing at the time of the crash.

Comment: thank, I didn't read what the function does, it's outputs to a debugger, so it's also possible to view output with attached SDK debugger?